# How to disable to entire pagination in Jqgrid temporarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, jqgrid

I have a situation to disable to whole pagination div of Jqgrid in one shot.
I have this following code to disable each functionality.But What if i add some more button in the pagination div. then i will have to write code to disable that.

```
> jQuery("#add_" +gridId).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
> jQuery("#first_pager").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
> jQuery("#prev_pager").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
> jQuery("#next_pager").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
> jQuery("#last_pager").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

Can anyone help on this

Comment: try `$.each('#pager_center td .ui-pg-button',function(){$(this).addClass('ui-state-disabled');});` applies to all buttons within `pager_center`

Comment: It's important that you include *in all your question* information about version of jqGrid, which you use and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). More recent version of jqGrid support either jQuery UI or Bootstrap. You choice is important. The values of `pager` and `toppager` options and the calls of `navGrid`, `inlineNav` and `navButtonAdd` are required too.

Comment: i am using jqGrid.4.4.3

Comment: The values of `pager` and `toppager` options and the calls of `navGrid`, `inlineNav` and `navButtonAdd` are required too. You use `jQuery("#add_" +gridId).addClass('ui-state-disabled')` which means that you want to disable "Add" button. Which other buttons you have? You wrote "What if i add some more button in the pagination div". You mean probably the **`navtable`** div (buttons of the navigator bar), because **pagination** div(s) (one can have two divs: in the top pager and on the bottom pager) don't contains any non-standard buttons.

Comment: Now the selector.addClass('ui-state-disabled'); is making the look grey. but it is not disabling. what to do?

Comment: @user3662273: Please include `@Oleg` if more as one person posted comments to your question. I didn't get any notification. You still describe the problem without any details. Which web browser you use? Do you have the problem that the button is disables, but it's clickable in IE, for example? It's known bug in some old versions of jqGrid (I'm not sure about 4.4.3). It's fixed later. I develop free jqGrid fork and I use **two** classes to disable: `ui-state-disabled` **and** `ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents` in jQuery UI, where **`.ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents { pointer-events: none; }`**.

Comment: @Oleg, It is still not disabling with the class 'ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents'. can you please help me

Comment: I can't help you if I don't know what you do. Adding of classes ui-state-disabled and ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents to buttons do work. I'm sure that makes errors in your code. You should provide the demo, which reproduces the problem. For example https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5w5h2Lgw/14/

Comment: @Oleg, This is my code.  jQuery('#pg_pager').find('td [class*="ui-pg-"').each(function(){
  jQuery(this).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
  jQuery(this).addClass('ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents');    
  });

Comment: @user3662273: What you post in not a demo. If you place the code on the wrong place it will not work. Look at my demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5w5h2Lgw/14/. You can see that it works.

Comment: @Oleg, I have found the solution in one of your best answers in stack overflow. Thanks!                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805832/jqgrid-prevent-pager-navigation

Comment: @user3662273: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.